# Does the word "uncovery" exist?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, word-form

Does the noun **uncovery** (noun of to uncover) exist?

I have seen this quite often in publications of nuclear reactor safety analyses.

For example: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0143817484900349

> Assessment of the uncertainties associated with the core **uncovery** time in TMI-type accidents

I cannot find the word in http://www.merriam-webster.com Or do you have to use the gerund **uncovering**?

Matthias

Comment: uncovery
See: disclosure
Burton's Legal Thesaurus, 4E. Copyright © 2007 The source :Thefreedictionary.com.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a technical term, referring to exposed (and therefore uncooled) tubes:

> Two separate accident scenarios are addressed. In the first scenario,
>   it is assumed that the non-safety grade startup feedwater system is
>   not available to provide feedwater to the steam generators. In this
>   event, the water level in the steam generators drops, resulting in
>   tube uncovery and there is flashing of a portion of the primary
>   coolant assumed to be leaking into the secondary side of the steam
>   generators. Also, the period of steaming is terminated at 1.5 hours
>   when the capacity of the passive residual heat removal system exceeds
>   the decay heat generation rate.

http://www.nrc.gov/reactors/new-reactors/design-cert/ap1000/dcd/Tier%202/Chapter%2015/15-3_r15.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The verb is **uncover**, and **uncovery** is used as an adjective in your example. It is quite possible that the word has been transformed into a more specific **jargon** usage specific to reactor core exposure.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is a good question. I checked several dictionaries for the word '*uncovery'* but could not find it.

TheFreeDictionary has an entry for this but it [does not clearly state anything on the page.](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/uncovery)

I think it is *not* widely used (COCA returns *one* result to the search 'uncovery'); MS word shows 'error' in the spelling and as I said, dictionaries including MM, OALD, Cambridge, WordWeb don't have such entry.

This seems to be a technical term or jargon in *some context*, not necessarily available on dictionaries. However, I had come across somewhere something like: "...leaving out an *uncovery* space on a glass.'

---

In addition, to make the verb 'to uncover' a noun, it would be ***'uncovering'*** i.e. a gerund word. [Uncovering is found](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/UNCOVERING) in dictionaries.

Comment: If "uncovery "is presented as a synonym to" disclosure " it has got its meaning.